# How to add Jquery script into html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in JQuery. I was playing with some JQuery, I visited this
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk5qtnf8/1/) . I want to make exactly form like this.
I copy all the code into my test.html. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    TEST
</title>

<script>

$(".container").on("change", ".a2 input[name^='selection_']", function 
(event) {
if ($(this).val() == "name") {
    $(this).parent().find('.url').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden',
            'display': 'none'
    });
    $(this).parent().find('.text').css({
        'visibility': 'visible',
            'display': 'block'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).parent().find('.text').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden',
            'display': 'none'
    });
    $(this).parent().find('.url').css({
        'visibility': 'visible',
            'display': 'block'
    });
    }
  });

$('.clone').click(function () {
var p = $('.a2').length;
var cloned = $('.a2:first').clone()
    .find('input:radio').attr('name', 'selection_' + ++p).end()
    .appendTo('.container');
});
</script>

<style>
.a2 .url {
visibility:hidden;
display:none;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="a2">
    <input type="radio" name="selection_1" value="name" checked="checked"
    />Name
    <input type="radio" name="selection_1" value="url" />URL
    <div class="text">
        <textarea name="name[]">Enter name:</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="url">
        <textarea name="url[]">http://</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="clone" value="Clone" />





</body>
</html>
```

The result of this code is, the button clone not working, same with the radio button. My question is, how to copy the jquery code in jsfiddle into html form. Thanks in advance

Comment: include the jquery script in your html make sure you load the jquery script before all you code

Comment: You have not included the main jQuery script in your code. Add that in your html head and your code should work

Comment: how to include it ?
i have include this <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> but still not working

Comment: put your code just before the </body> or put your js inside document .ready

Comment: a) include jquery, b) wrap your code in `$(function() { ... your code ... });` so your code waits for DOM to be ready before accessing DOM

Comment: Thankyou so much, it working fine. sorry for my useless post. :) 
Im still new in Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [JQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) or use its CDN (the same as the one in the snippet), then put it inside the `head` above all other `js` files (if you have more) so that `JQuery` will be loaded first before all the other scripts

It would be preferable if you include the script after the `body` tag so that all elements have been loaded before the scripts fire.

**Note:** I didn't separate the `css` and `scripts` in the snippet so that OP can see where to place the needed components

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    TEST
  </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .a2 .url {
      visibility: hidden;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a2">
      <input type="radio" name="selection_1" value="name" checked="checked" />Name
      <input type="radio" name="selection_1" value="url" />URL
      <div class="text">
        <textarea name="name[]">Enter name:</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="url">
        <textarea name="url[]">http://</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="clone" value="Clone" />
</body>
<script>
  $(".container").on("change", ".a2 input[name^='selection_']", function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "name") {
      $(this).parent().find('.url').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden',
        'display': 'none'
      });
      $(this).parent().find('.text').css({
        'visibility': 'visible',
        'display': 'block'
      });
    } else {
      $(this).parent().find('.text').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden',
        'display': 'none'
      });
      $(this).parent().find('.url').css({
        'visibility': 'visible',
        'display': 'block'
      });
    }
  });

  $('.clone').click(function() {
    var p = $('.a2').length;
    var cloned = $('.a2:first').clone()
      .find('input:radio').attr('name', 'selection_' + ++p).end()
      .appendTo('.container');
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, it working fine. sorry for my useless post. :) 
Im still new in Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery script on your head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, it working fine. sorry for my useless post. :) 
Im still new in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `jquery.js` file from [www.jquery.com/download/](https://jquery.com/download/) then put in the one place :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path of your jquery.js file + your jquery file name "  ><script>
```

**Note** : You should write this code before your scripts !

Comment: Why are you wrapping it with single-quote?

Comment: i fixed it .no it is true.tnx about reaport my mistake :)